# How do I make a shell script to compile a C# program portably?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, shell, nuget

Ok super noob question. I made a c# program in visual studio, which involves using a Nuget package. Now I need to make a shell script which can compile and run the program portably on Unix or Linux systems. How do I do this (assuming I even can...)? I tried digging the dll for the package out of file system and compiling with:

> c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\csc.exe /t:exe /out:Program.exe Program.cs /reference:Priority_Queue.dll

But while this compiled, the program crashed on run. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you have the DLL file in the same directory as the EXE on the linux box when you tried running it? What was the error when it crashed?

Comment: That won't work. You will need to build it in .NET Core or Mono to run on Unix. The "standard" .NET Framework only works on Windows.

Comment: I'm actually not using a linux box at the moment, I'm just trying to check that it works by compiling it with the windows command cmd. So I guess a better phasing of this question would be 'is passing the .dll from the Nuget package like this all I need to do?" Anyway, the error I'm getting is a file not found exception.

Comment: @BrunoLM So there's no way I can get it into a form that can be compiled on unix? I guess if the package is open-source I can just copy the relevant material into a file or something...

Comment: You can, but you have to use Mono compiler http://www.mono-project.com/ I've never used it otherwise I would give you an example or something